# Simple solution to 1000n^3> 2^n without Lambert and "W"

Tags: algorithms

I need to determine for what range of n the algorithm that costs $1000n^3$ is faster than one that costs $2^n$, now I solved it on wolfram alpha and I know the answer is >= 24.
The issue is I have to prove it with using the math only and I don't understand the "W" thing in the solution (nor at this class (Data Structures)) we are supposed to have access to "Lambert?" formula).
So for each attempt I end up somewhere like:
$$log_2(10n) = \frac{n}{3}$$
Or something along these lines, I just don't know how to arrive at n = 24 without guessing like if it was 25 is too big.. etc from this point.

tl;dr:
is there a simple cubic or logarithmic solution (or Calc I even) to:
$$ 1000n^3 < 2^n $$
Thank you.

Comment: You don't need to do anything fancy. You just need to show that $1000 n^3 > 2^n$ holds for $1 \le n \le 23$, and doesn't hold for $n \ge 24$. You can directly check that for $24$ and for $23$. Next, you can do the $\ge 24$ part by induction (using $(\frac{n+1}{n})^3 < 2$). Then, you can similarly do most of $\le 23$ part by backward induction (as long as $(\frac{n+1}{n})^3 < 2$ holds, i.e. for $n \ge 4$). It leaves you with $n \in \{1,2,3\}$, which you check directly.

Comment: Once I directly show by checking manually that means I know the answer already, which I am trying to avoid, I need to show how I arrived at it, but without using Lambert if possible. @Dmitry

Comment: "I need to show how I arrived at it" - what makes you think so?

Comment: "In your answer describe not only what the answer is but how you arrived at the answer.", guessing it's 24 is valid but does not answer my original question, simply put, anyway to solve this without Lamber and the W thing?

Comment: It's crucial that both functions are strictly increasing with $n>1.$ So if the exponential is larger than the cubic for some minimal $n$ and smaller for  all integers $n'<n,$  you are done.

Comment: @kodlu but how do I show that n' begins at 24, without guessing?

Comment: Strictly speaking you cannot. You can use approximations like $2^n$ is approximately a thousand for $n=10,$ a million for $n=20,$ etc and the approximations to $1000n^3$ are even simpler. To save some computation you can guess a really large $n$ if $n$ is too large, halve it, that is too small take the middle point, etc. This is called the bisection method.

Comment: I would ask your instructor what kind of explanation they expect. If I were an instructor, in this example, "looked at the plot" would be a perfectly valid explanation, as well as "I've written the program which computed the difference for the first 100 values" or, if they want something you could do by hand: "Clearly, the answer is between 20 and 30: <simple calculations> - so I just used a binary search in this range".